# HTML5 canvas can't apply sw filter

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, filter

I want to write code that can filter the source of an image and return the data that it can be used as source for an image tag in the DOM. Therfore I created a virtual canvas. At the moment it only works with a real canvas within the DOM, even though the dimension is wrong. I only want the converted image source and no canvas in the DOM.

this is how I need it but it doesn't work: [**js fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NEF8n/9/)

this one works with wrong img dimension and unwanted canvas in the DOM: [**js fiddle2**](http://jsfiddle.net/NEF8n/8/)

js:

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function () {

var helperCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = helperCanvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.width =  image.width;
ctx.height =  image.height; 
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, helperCanvas.width, helperCanvas.height); 
  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, helperCanvas.width, helperCanvas.height);

    filter(imageData);

    data_as_source = ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0 ).toURL();

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = data_as_source;
    context.drawImage(img,0,0);
}

image.src = ....
```

Comment: i don't see a "canvas in the DOM" in the code shown... and besides, without canvas, how are you going to get the pixel data?

Comment: I want to use the like int this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NEF8n/9/) but ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0 ) does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your demo code, you should be changing the temporary canvas width/height, not the context’s.

```
    helperCanvas.width =  image.width;
    helperCanvas.height =  image.height;
```

Here is code with a test filter that just turns all non-transparent pixels red.

It also renders the filtered canvas image to an image on the page.

BTW, when creating an image object, there is a new Chrome bug that can be avoided if you create like this:

```
    var img=document.createElement("img");
```

Fiddle that must be viewed in Chrome or FF (IE==CORS failure):  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/LeGD5/

Here is code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img=document.createElement("img");
    img.onload=function(){
        canvas.width=img.width;
        canvas.height=img.height;
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height);

        // test -- turn every non-transparent pixel red
        var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        var pixels = imgData.data; // get pixel data
        for (var i = 0; i < pixels.length; i +=4)
        {
            // if this pixel is not transparent,
            // mask it in pure red
            if(pixels[i+3]>0){
                pixels[i]=255;    // this is the red component of the pixel
                pixels[i+1]=0;    // this is the green component of the pixel
                pixels[i+2]=0;    // this is the blue component of the pixel
                pixels[i+3]=255;  // this is the alpha component of the pixel
            }
        }
        ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);    

        var theImage=document.getElementById("theImage");
        theImage.src=canvas.toDataURL();
    }
    img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/KoolAidMan.png";



}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <img id="theImage" width=300 height=300>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you had a couple bugs in your dataURL part, but this seems to work:

```
var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function () {

    var helperCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = helperCanvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.width =  image.width;
    ctx.height =  image.height; 
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, helperCanvas.width, helperCanvas.height); 
      var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, helperCanvas.width, helperCanvas.height);

        filter(imageData);
        ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0 );
        //context.drawImage(img,0,0);

        data_as_source = helperCanvas.toDataURL();

        var img = new Image();
        img.src = data_as_source;
        img.style.border="3px solid red";// for demo sake
        document.body.appendChild(img); // for demo sake
    }
```